# thread will linger despite being asked to die via interruption

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some Java code like this:

```
IntStream.range(0, N)
        .parallel()
        .forEach(
            i -> {
// do some work
            });
```

and see following warnings when this code is run:

```
[WARNING] thread Thread[#73,ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-8,5,] was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least 15000msecs
[WARNING] thread Thread[#73,ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-8,5,] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[#74,ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9,5,] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[#75,ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-10,5,] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[#76,ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-11,5,] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[#77,ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-12,5,] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[#78,ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-13,5,] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] thread Thread[#79,ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-14,5,] will linger despite being asked to die via interruption
[WARNING] NOTE: 7 thread(s) did not finish despite being asked to via interruption. This is not a problem with exec:java, it is a problem with the running code. Although not serious, it should be remedied.
```

I cannot provide a minimally reproducible example without copying pasting all the code in the lambda which is not feasible but I have verified following:

- there is no exception thrown in the lambda
- the warnings disappear if I run my application using `mvn spring-boot:run` but are present if the application is executed via `mvn exec:java`. As I understand, the former spawns a new JVM whereas the latter does not.

I would appreciate any help or tips to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best as I can tell, this is yet another Maven issue as the error or warnings are not there if the code is executed directly via `java`.

I think the explanation is that when a program is executed using `mvn exec:java` the program does not run on the main thread. Maven runs the program  on a worker thread [[1](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.java#L257)]:

```
Thread bootstrapThread = new Thread(
                threadGroup,
                () -> {
                    int sepIndex = mainClass.indexOf('/');

                    final String bootClassName;
...
mainHandle.invoke(arguments); // runs our main class
...
        bootstrapThread.start();
        joinNonDaemonThreads(threadGroup);
...
```

and the threads in the `ForkJoin` common pool do not shutdown until the main thread exits [[2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)]:

> This pool is statically constructed; its run state is unaffected by attempts to shutdown() or shutdownNow(). However this pool and any ongoing processing are automatically terminated upon program System.exit(int).

Thus interrupting them will not shut them down [[3](https://github.com/mojohaus/exec-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.java#L434)].

```
// executed as a result of call to joinNonDaemonThreads
if (thread.isAlive()) // generally abnormal
        {
            getLog().warn("thread " + thread + " was interrupted but is still alive after waiting at least "
                    + timeoutMsecs + "msecs");
        }
```

Just my guess.